# finite dimensional Banach space vs $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

In my Analysis course we have proven most theorems either in a "finite dimensional Banach space" or in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example the [implicite function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Definitions) requires $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a space. But the Taylor series was proven in  a "finite dimensional Banach space". Since $\mathbb{R}^n$
is a special case of a finite dimensional Banach space, those results can only be used in such a setting until proven otherwise.

So what are  the differences of those settings? 
What can I use in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is not there in the more general case. Since we didnt use a scalar product, maybe just the underlying fields (complex or real numbers) would make a difference.
But like $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not ordered.